# Como definir opções de impressão via javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, impressão

É possível? Gostaria por exemplo de retirar a margem padrão e retirar cabeçalho e rodapé. Já abrir a janela de impressão com essas opções definidas.

Comment: Acho que uma resposta completa seria a do Erlon, porém com o complemento do Beterraba, pois pode ser uma alternativa válida para alguns casos. Se houver uma resposta assim marco como a correta e apago esse comentario. Acho que dessa forma poderá ajudar mais futuros visitantes.

Comment: [Esta Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1992798/1287812) tem uma resposta deletada que aponta pra isto: https://code.google.com/p/jzebra/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É possível utilizando CSS, através do media type `print`

Suponha que você queira esconder a tag `header` quando solicitado a impressão:

```
<header>
   <h1> Preciso sumir na impressão</h1>
<header>
<p> Eu quero aparecer na impressão </p>
```

No seu CSS, você deve definir:

```
@media print {
  header {
    display: none
  }
}
```

Comment: Isso já ajuda bastante +1

Answer (score 4):

Essas configuração são do browser e não da página.
Há um tempo atrás pesquisei muito sobre o assunto também e acabei resolvendo o problema definindo essas configurações de impressão como configurações do browser no documento de pré requisitos do sistema.

Portanto a menos que seja possível com JavaScript manipular as configurações do browser isso **não** é possível de ser feito.

Comment: Sim, há um tempo atrás me deparei com a mesma questão e depois me conformei com a impossibilidade. `+1`